# How i can get all the keys from a string which somehow looks like json string

Tags: java

I have a string like below

```
   {"226167":"hawaiii","3193":"california"}
```

Can I use some java method  to get all the key values (226167,3193 ) in a List object. If yes How it's done...?

Comment: why JSONTokener? why not just parse it into a JSONObject (which has getNames()) ?

Comment: I don't know .....can u please tell me how...

Comment: well i just saw my project has got no JSONObject so probably can i use JSONTokener only....

Comment: or is there any other method i can do this stuff..?

Comment: `JSONTokener` (what a strange name!) and `JSONObject` are from the same library! How can you have access to one, but not the other?

Comment: because i having only this single file in project directory....

Comment: You should add the whole librairy to your project.

Answer (score 5):

```
 String json =  "{'226167':'hawaiii','3193':'california'}";
 JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
 Iterator<String> yourKeys = object.keys();
 for( String s : yourKeys)
    System.out.println( s );
```

You need the JSON.Org library to run this (http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html)

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: @user: and **why**? There is a great tool for what you want and re-writing it in something else is tiresome. Unless you can give a **good** reason on why you can't use this approach, this is what you should use.