# Getting property of an object which has non-fixed keys

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

Assume that I get this JSon Response from webservice:

```
{
    "id":13,
    "name":"Alireza",
    "required_id":"14",
    "all_friends_id_and_name":{
        "28":"Hassan",
        "21":"Mohammad",
        "68":"Ali",
        "14":"Taha",
        "96":"Darya"
    }
}
```

In this response `required_id` value specifies that I need a friend name with id 14, so in `all_friends_id_and_name` object I should get the value of "14" (Taha) and use it in my app.

I'm using retrofit2 and gson libraries.

How to get property of an object which has non-fixed keys?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419217/to-get-all-the-keys-in-jsonobject-into-string-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091054/how-i-can-get-all-the-keys-from-a-string-which-somehow-looks-like-json-string , I dont think gson can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Native approach, You can  Try with [**`Iterator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)  .

> An iterator is an object that enables a programmer to traverse a
>   container, particularly lists.

```
 "all_friends_id_and_name":{
        "28":"Hassan",
        "21":"Mohammad",
        "68":"Ali",
        "14":"Taha",
        "96":"Darya"
    }
```

For the above section, Your **`LOGIC`** will be

```
     JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject("Json_response");
          Iterator  iteratorObj = jsonData .keys();
           while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
            {
                String str_json_Key = (String)iteratorObj.next();
                 // Print=28,21....96
             }
```

Comment: so there is no solution using gson library? and if the answer is "No", how to get "all_friends_id_and_name" value as string? it's a retrofit request.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali Sorry sir, AFAIK, Retrofit will not help for this case.

Comment: It doesn't solve, yet. As you said Retrofit will not help for this case, So I decided to tell webservice developers to change the webservice response.

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali Solved now?

Comment: Yes, it has solved. we changed the response. thank you

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali Move ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Json:

```
{
    "id":13,
    "name":"Alireza",
    "required_id":"14",
    "all_friends_id_and_name":{
        "28":"Hassan",
        "21":"Mohammad",
        "68":"Ali",
        "14":"Taha",
        "96":"Darya"
    }
}
```

Try by doing like this :

```
 try {

     JSONObject jsonObject; // it should be your above JsonObject 

            Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();

            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) keys.next();
                System.out.println("Mykey: " + key + " value: " + jsonObject.getString(key));    
            }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```